# Dynamic binding in Knockout click event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, sweetalert

I am using an alert plugin on my website. The alert prompts the user to select on of the multiple options. Something like the image. [image]

The issues is that buttons are generated dynamically like this

```
var html = "<div id='reject-options'></br> ";
html += "<a href='#' class='button alert small radius' data-bind='click: $root.blacklistOrderForMatch'>" + Texts.Order + "</a> </br>";
```

The click bind doesn't apply because the bindings are already in place when the website loads. How can I achieve this? Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: you need to reapply bindings/cleanNode (one way) . can you share a sample fiddle with some code demonstrates your cause .

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27087/.

Comment: The fact that you're constructing html as strings (with data-bindings) suggests you're not modeling your view as thoroughly as you should. Anything you can do building html strings can be handled with various bindings. Possibly components would be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use:

```
ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById('reject-options'));
//self is your view model
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27112/)

Second parameter of `ko.applyBindings` is the node to which you are applying bindings.